# BBM SDK - How to get simulators communicating?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator

Suffice to say I'm struggling quite a bit with my foray into BlackBerry development. In trying to get the BBM SDK sample apps (platformdemo and  tictactoe) working, I fear I've taken a step backwards.

You see, I initially had it set up so that two BlackBerry simulators could message each other using BBM.

Now, that no longer works, and I simply can't figure out why. Why would the BBM communication not work?

I'm running:
BBM SDK Beta 4_03_10_2011
BlackBerry_Simulators_6.0.0.313_9800
MDS v3.5.3 (I've verified that this is running correctly, downloaded the unlimited strength encryption policy jars etc.)
Java JDK v1.6.0_25 (JRE v6)

I've uninstalled and reinstalled everything, including Java. I run the MDS first using this command line:

`"run.bat" -log.console.dump -feature "bbm,keynego,monitor,servicebook,cmimep2p,ep2p,registration,ippp,http,httpm,httpc,httpcm,defaulthandler" -webconfig all`

then start up the simulators using the included sim1.bat and sim2.bat files:

Sim1:

`@echo off
fledge.exe /app=Jvm.dll /handheld=9800 /session=Sim1 /app-param=JvmAlxConfigFile:9800.xml /data-port=0x4d44 /data-port=0x4d4e /pin=0x2100000A /app-param=regVersion=3 /app-param=regDestIP=127.0.0.1 /app-param=regDestPort=19785 /app-param=regSrcPort=19788 /app-param=DisableSyncServiceRecord /title="BlackBerry 9800-1 Simulator"`

Sim2:

`@echo off
fledge.exe /app=Jvm.dll /handheld=9800 /session=Sim2 /app-param=JvmAlxConfigFile:9800.xml /data-port=0x4d44 /data-port=0x4d4e /pin=0x2100000B /app-param=regVersion=3 /app-param=regDestIP=127.0.0.1 /app-param=regDestPort=19785 /app-param=regSrcPort=19789 /app-param=DisableSyncServiceRecord /title="BlackBerry 9800-2 Simulator"`

I forgot to mention that both simulators can connect to the Internet via the browser (which they cannot do when the MDS is not running properly) but cannot see each other on BBM after adding each other as contacts using the provided pins (2100000A and 2100000B).

What could be going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

For anyone interested, I managed to solve my own problem.

I have no idea why, but previously I could simply add a new contact, put in their BBM pin and they would show up on my contacts list within BBM, ready for me to start a chat with them.

This time, I had to take a screenshot of **simulator 1's** QR code, save it out in Photoshop, then use that image on **simulator 2** to invite **simulator 1**.

For some reason, this allowed the contacts to see each other. I don't own a BlackBerry so I have no idea but I really can't imagine this is the way it's supposed to work since it requires both users to be in the same physical location. However, it's the only way I could get it working and it proves that the rest of my setup (MDS) and so on is correct.

Comment: +1 - didn't solve any of my problems with bbm, but what a creative approach!